How to fix missing street paths or broken paths in a Local map?
OpenStreetMap provides public maps that anyone can use, which is great. In the USA and other large countries, there might be many routes and locations discovered and added.
In Pakistan we have different ride apps. Yango has something that really caught my eye: they are not using Google Maps, and their maps are pretty impressive. Regarding the location I checked:

Below is image for google maps:

And here is for openstreetmaps.org:

I live near that location, so I can confirm that there is a way present there that Yango is showing. That street, however, is a little narrow; a car cannot go through, only a bike can travel. I also know Yango does not provide bike rides, so I confirm that they did not use drivers' data to create that map.
I am curious how they did it, while in OpenStreetMap.org the path is blocked. I agree that in OpenStreetMap, people can voluntarily edit the map, which is why some paths might be blocked.
What I want is not to use Google Maps in my application to avoid being dependent on a big competitor. Yango does not provide integration or APIs, and other map solutions seem inaccurate. I just tried them for my own location, and it seems really challenging because if I use open source, it will choose a longer path for the destination. I don’t think they manually corrected the paths and chose the base map of OpenStreetMap, but this is going to be a problem for me if I use those open source maps without correcting them.
It is not possible for me to manually find all paths of that nature and correct them all. I don’t want to do it for the whole country, just for one city, Lahore. I also don’t want to cover all small paths, but at least most of the paths.
Is there any way or solution I can implement?
Here are the URLs if you want to see them on your own on the web.
Here is Yango location
Yango Location which i am reffering to
Google maps
Google Location which i am reffering to
and here is openstreetmaps
openstreetmaps

I would encourage you to use open data. OpenStreetMap can be a very good choice, even if you found it a bit inaccurate in your area. As you wrote: "people can voluntarily edit the map" - you can enhance/modify the data as well, especially if you know there is a bike-wide link to main street. Please enhance the data, extend the road, link it to other. You are working on mobile app. Then you can collect the gps data from many mobiles, aggregate them and use to enhance OSM data as well. If you have an Orthophoto map provided by any government authority - use it as a base to enhance OSM.

@GrzegorzSapijaszko Can you join this discussion for future. I would really appreciate it. https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79313601/correcting-osm-data-in-country-where-much-of-the-streets-are-missing-or-broken

Hey, don't know what's your business plans, but you might be interested in: https://rb.ru/opinion/how-to-make-gps-system/ or https://www.localair.uk/ -- it's about air quality, but a GPS would be sufficient. On the other hand, you can build a local community (see https://community.openstreetmap.org/) who will create/enhance OSM data: GPS track collection by any phone, streetcomplete app for data enhancement while going outside. If you know someone with drone, why not to use it for mapping? https://opendronemap.org/ as a starting point. The are many opportunities/ways to make it.

@GrzegorzSapijaszko Thanks for these resources! You are Awesome!
